# Debugging $.getJSON() delivering different results when using named arguments

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, .htaccess, requirejs

I'm pulling my hair out over what seems to be very odd behavior in jQuery.

```
 define ['jquery', 'models/ConfigModel'], ($,  ConfigModel) ->
   class MyController
     initialize: () ->
       confData = $.getJSON('/config.json', (data) -> console.log data)
```

This works just fine. It returns the content of config.json

```
   define ['jquery', 'models/ConfigModel'], ($,  ConfigModel) ->
     class MyController
       initialize: () ->
         confData = $.getJSON
           url: '/config.json' 
           success: (data) -> console.log data
```

This returns the content of index.html, which is likely due to the server's .htaccess file.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(js|css|media|api|pie|templates|config.json) - [L,NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.html
   RewriteRule .* index.html [QSA,L]
```

I've also tried using JS in the Chrome console, and got the same results.

```
   //works well
   $.getJSON('/config.json', function(data) {console.log(data)}) 
   //index.html
   $.getJSON({url:'/config.json', success: function(data) {console.log(data)}})
```

Since I have a workaround, the solution is less important to me than anyone's ideas regarding ways to debug situations such as this.

**Edit:**

```
    $.getJSON({url:'/config.json', success: function(data) {console.log(data)}})
    XHR finished loading: "http://site.dev/[object%20Object]]".

     $.getJSON('/config.json', function(data) {console.log(data)})
     XHR finished loading: "http://site.dev/config.json".
```

Comment: If you observe this request being made using Chrome or Safari Web Inspector (or something similar), what URL is it sending the request to?

Comment: See edit, that certainly seems to explain a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the footprint of `getJSON`:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] )
```

I copied this from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). You simply *don't* use this function the way you wanted to.

You should use `$.ajax()` if you want to pass an object with all the settings.

Comment: Thank you, I assumed it followed the lead of $.ajax()

Comment: @JoshRumbut Yeah, I know that feeling. Most of the time sleeping is your best option. When I'm tired, sometimes I do more damage than progress... :)